# What are the rules for collection names in SOLR?

Tags: database, solr, nosql, spring-data

What is the naming ruleset for collections that should be followed, or  in other words what are the inacceptable characters for a collection name? (for example, in elasticsearch you can't use some symbols ",:? etc..." for naming indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found an answer in solr [docs](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/aliases.html):

> Throughout Solr there are limitations on the allowable characters in
> collection names. Any characters other than ASCII alphanumeric
> characters (A-Za-z0-9), hyphen (-) or underscore (_) are replaced with
> an underscore when calculating the collection name for a category.

Update:
Collection names must consist entirely of periods, underscores, hyphens, and alphanumerics as well not start with a hyphen